# How to bind custom getView to ListView adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to creat a Customer `ListView` I have setup the layout and `getView` method
But I am not sure how to bind that new view from getView to my adapter?

I have a `feedClass` extending from `ArrayAdapter<String>` in which I have `getView` method:

```
public class FeedClass extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;

public FeedClass(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.feed_item_layout);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_layout, parent,
            false);

    ImageView tweetPicture = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.tweetPicture);
    TextView tweetDescription = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.tweetDescription);
    TextView legends = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.legends);

    tweetPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile);
    tweetDescription.setText("Hello");
    legends.setText("Legends");

//How to show this data in the ListView?

    return rowView;
}
```

}

And in `MainActivity` which extends from `ListActivity` I have this:

```
private void activateFeed() {       
//Now I Want to show data in ListView that i am setting in getView?
    ArrayAdapter<String> adptr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.feed_item_layout, ?); //What to pass here?

    setListAdapter(adptr);

}
```

Currently it is using an array, now I don’t know how pass the custom view from getView to this? Please help.

Comment: Use extends Activity, set your adapter in listview.

Comment: You are using custom adapter??

Comment: @Raghunandan I think yes. Maven you are using custom adapter or not ?

Comment: @Hardy in that case op wants to know how to use the array in `getView`? Its not clear to me

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes you are right even i am not clear.

Comment: i dont need that array `values`, that was just for testing purpose. Now i need to show data which i am setting in `getView`

Comment: @Maven pls elaborate **Currently it is using an array, now I don’t know how pass the custom view from getView to this**

Comment: @Maven show us `feedClass`

Comment: i have edited the question, may be its clear now, please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: @Maven Is google blocked in your system ?

Comment: ^ yes and so bing, yahoo and I developed the understanding for the not-so-much code I have written till now myself through meditation.

Comment: @Maven could u check view is null or not

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a Custom Adapter by name feedClass and you want to set the same to `ListActivity`

```
  LayoutInflater inflater;
  public FeedClass(Context context)
  {
     super(context, R.layout.feed_item_layout);
     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
     // no need to initialize everytime in getview
     // so you can initialize in the constructor
  }
```

Also use a `ViewHolder` pattern for smooth scrolling and performance

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Now

```
 FeedClass fc = new FeedClass(MainActivity.this);
 setListAdapter(fc);
```

Example i found on the net

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/

Comment: Thankyou for the answer and extra suggestions, I am trying your example with the help of the tutorial now.

Answer (score 0):

ListActivity has its own adapter implementation which you have done right way
but if you want to use your own instance of Adapter class then you need to extend your activity file to extends Activity and then you can use your adapters getView method

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the BaseAdapter and override the getView method

```
public class FeedClass extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

public FeedClass(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arrayList.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_layout, parent,
            false);

    ImageView tweetPicture = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.tweetPicture);
    TextView tweetDescription = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.tweetDescription);
    TextView legends = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.legends);

    tweetPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile);
    // set the text from the ArrayList
    tweetDescription.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    // set the text from the ArrayList
    legends.setText(arrayList.get(position));

    return rowView;
}
}
```